# Get the type of a delegated attribute in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates

I have two classes Individual and Person, where an Individual represents a real person and Person a real person in a particular setting. I use delegate of attribute setters, getters and dirty tests (where needed) like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :individual
    delegate  :firstname, :lastname, ..., :firstname=, ..., :to => :individual
    ...
end
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :persons, :dependent => :destroy
    ...
end
```

Everything works fine, except that my forms (I use Formtastic) will treat all delegated attributes as strings. I can fix this by adding attribute type information in the forms, e.g.

```
<%= f.input :has_car, :as => :boolean %>
```

but this is not very elegant. But I can't figure out how, or if it is possible, to delegate the attribute type information